# leaflet.js - how to identify a popup?

Tags: javascript, onclick, popup, leaflet, identifier

I would like to create a marker together with a popup which contains a button that, when clicked, shall trigger a JQuery-Ajax-Function in order to edit the popup's content.

Using the onclick()-property for the button, I can't seem to find a way to pass the popup's coordinates over to the Ajax-Function. I want to pass the coordinates, since as far as I know that's the only way to clearly identify each popup / marker.

This is my code so far:

```
function onMapClick(eventData) {
    var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(eventData.latlng)
        .setContent("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"editMarker(" + eventData.latlng + ")\" value=\"Click to edit!\">")

    L.marker(eventData.latlng, { draggable : true })
        .bindPopup(popup)
        .on("click", openMarker)
        .on("contextmenu", deleteMarker)
        .on("dblclick", editMarker)
        .addTo(map);
}

function editMarker(eventData) {
    alert("Editing marker at " + eventData);
}
```

However, this way the parameter for onclick() is "LatLng(xx, -yy)" which of course results in an undefined function call. I've found no way to obtain the pure coordinates of the popup in order to pass them to the edit-function.

What would be the best way to a) clearly identify a popup and b) to pass that ID to another function?

Answer (score 0):

All leaflet objects have a `_leaflet_id` associated with them so you should be able to use that as your id.

You can also bind to the `open` event that is fired when a popup is opening. That event passes a reference to the popup that is opening. You can bind to and use like this:

```
popup.on("open", popupOpen); 

// some other code as needed    

function popupOpen(pop) {
    this.currentPop = pop;
    console.log(pop.target._leaflet_id);
}
```